# Поддержка множества открытых соединений

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x

Нужно решение, которое позволит держать в активном состоянии соединение с эмуляцией браузера.
Пример: на сайте есть счётчик активных пользователей (не зарегистрированных), подсчёт идёт не по уникальным ip, а просто если кука не совпадает ни с одним из активных == новый юзер.

Буду рад любой идее, если в теории это можно реализовать на Python или C#.

Я не прошу готового кода, нужен просто алгоритм и библиотека, которая может подобное.